# How can I use titlesec without changing CHAPTER ONE to CHAPTER 1

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I have a week to submit my Ph.D thesis, done in latex, and have ran into a strange difficulty. Before introducing `{\usepackage[rm,tiny,compact, bf]{titlesec} }` which was necessary in order to unify all titles in the entire thesis to document size as per university requirements, my chapters headings read CHAPTER ONE (etc). this was accomplished using

```
\usepackage{fmtcount,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\chaptermark}{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Now they read CHAPTER 1 (etc), which is unacceptable! So how can I retain the CHAPTER ONE (etc) format and still use titlesec? Urgent response will be highly appreciated, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Would you please provide a mock-up of your document in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so we can replicate problem? Help us help you... Obviously [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) doesn't use `\@makechapterhead` to set its titles...

Comment: You shall have to use the advanced interface of titlesec, at least for chapters, somrthing like `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries}{\chaptername \Numberstring{chapter}}{…}{…}`.

Comment: Thanks Werner. This preamble produced CHAPTER ONE in my thesis:

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\bfseries\footnotesize\center TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\center \small CHAPTER}
\newcommand{\cchapter}[1]{\chapter[#1]{\centering #1}}
\usepackage{fmtcount,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\chaptermark}{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage[rm,tiny,compact, bf]{titlesec}

Comment: It produced the CHAPTER ONE format, until I introduced the \usepackage[rm,tiny,compact, bf]{titlesec} line of code. This reverted it to CHAPTER 1.

Answer (score 1):

This code hopefully results in something close to what you want. I replaced loading `fancyhdr` with `titleps`, a sibling of `titlesec` which eases (re-)defining page styles :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, openright, twoside]{report}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}

\usepackage[pagestyles, clearempty]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{fmtcount,etoolbox}

\newpagestyle{Headings}{%
\sethead[][\sectiontitle][]{}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername} \NUMBERstring{chapter}}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\normalsize\filcenter}{\chaptername \Numberstring{chapter}}{1\baselineskip}{}
\pagestyle{Headings}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}
\chapter{A first chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\section{A first section}
\lipsum[2-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]